# C# Random Reset, problemilla: repite secuencia

Tags: c#, random

para mis simulaciones de fisica, me hice 10 matrices de 800 datos, de momento los relleno alea para test.

NO hay manera, me salen las 10 graficas calcadas.

la cosa parece ir bien si pongo un break poin tras la carga de las 4 Ks, la puse hay para confirmar que funciona, y si, funciona, FUNCIONA CON LOS BREAKPOINS. (si paso de ellos a mitad de vueltas, a partir de ahi falla)

lo que me lleva a pensar que la semilla la toma del reloj, y al ser muy rapido no cambia.

si pongo la definicion del Rand fuera de la funcion tambien me fallaba, arriba el de defi de prototipos, ¿o como le llamais a eso los informaticos?

creo que intentare con un retardillo.

```
        public void Test()
    {
        Random Rand = new Random();   //poniendolo tras el public Class ClassReg tambien fallaba
        double k1 = Rand.NextDouble();
        double k2 = Rand.NextDouble();
        double k3 = Rand.NextDouble();
        double k4 = Rand.NextDouble();  //4 de las variables que siempre pilla las mismas//Aqui el breack point, 
        for (int i = 0; i < 800; i++)
        {
            lee[i].d = 0.5 + 0.8 * k3 * Math.Sin((i + 2 * Rand.NextDouble() - 10) * 0.2*k1) + 0.4 * k4 * Math.Cos((i + 3 * Rand.NextDouble() - 5) * 0.25*k2);// no os asusteis esto genera ondas, es irrelevante
            ///lee[i].d = i/800.0;  //opcion genera una diago en pantalla, 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Prepara la semilla usando alguna función pseudoaleatoria, previa. Aún en caso de que opere uniforme (reloj) habrá suficiente diferencia entre semillas para garantizar que la matrices carguen diferente.

Comment: Por favor no coloques solucionado al título de tu pregunta, si ya tienes la solución entonces con publicarla y eventualmente marcarla como aceptada alcanza amigo :)

Comment: ¿Y como la marco como aceptada?.
Anda ! ! ! , se arreglo solo

Answer (score 0):

LA RAIZ del problema: quiero ver 10 lineas similares, ¿que mejor que definir una clase generica y crear 10 objetos?.

SI, pero en la clase meti Test(), que genera las lineas aleatorias, y en esa clase esta el ramdom.

al crear los 10 objetos, todos nacen con la misma secuencia. (o esa es mi sospecha)

LA SOLUCION: 
un unico randon fuera de esa clase.

intente lo de la semilla, retardos, hasta mi hice mi propia randon, nada funciono